# Jquery onclick event not firing from href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this href in my html:

```
<a id="m_MC_hl6_8" class="no_loaderbox button_link inline_block " href="somelink" target="_self">link</a>
```

When clicked on the link, a div is shown to show a waiting box.

For this specific link I don't want that so I wrote a piece of jquery to hide the div when clicked on the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a.no_loaderbox', function(e) {
    $('.loaderBox').hide();
  });
});
```

But the line with hide is never hit.

I can't use the id because the link is dynamically created.

What am I missing here?

Comment: e.preventDefault();  you should prevent the link

Answer (score 0):

You can either `return false` or use `e.preventDefault` as [Adel Elkhodary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7352974/adel-elkhodary) mentioned in the comments above. Then select the correct element and apply the method `hide()`.

Here is the working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a.no_loaderbox', function(e) {
    $('.no_loaderbox').hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="m_MC_hl6_8" class="no_loaderbox button_link inline_block " href="somelink" target="_self">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false or e.preventDefault were not the answers I was looking for.

I got the problem resolved by binding the event directly on the element $('a') instead of with $(document) and class.